# Remove password value Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have in my view the following helper

```
 <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "form-control borderradiusnone",:placeholder => t(:password_confirmation, scope:[:attributes] ), :autocomplete => "off",:required => true , :maxlength => 16%>
```

the problem that I have is when my users are using IE7, IE8 (yes I have to give support to this browsers) this fields are shown as follow

[image: likes this]

Basically because the markup render like this

[image: like this]

Now, I tried using passing nil and string empty to the helper and it doesn't work

```
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :value => nil, :class => "form-control borderradiusnone",:placeholder => t(:password_confirmation, scope:[:attributes] ), :autocomplete => "off",:required => true , :maxlength => 16%>

<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,:value => "" ,:class => "form-control borderradiusnone",:placeholder => t(:password_confirmation, scope:[:attributes] ), :autocomplete => "off",:required => true , :maxlength => 16%>
```

I already solved this with jquery but this a messy solution, but I wanted to know why I cannot set the value from the helper

FYI: autocomplete is not a solution does not work for old browsers